# Unable to submit JSON request in PHPUnit on Slim Framework

Tags: json, slim

How can I resolve `HttpBadRequestException` when using PHPUnit to send a JSON request? I have a PHPUnit test in Slim Framework 4.5 that is sending a JSON request. When I get the form data in the controller, an `HttpBadRequestException` is thrown with the message `Malformed JSON input.` I can send cURL JSON requests fine. When I have it implemented in PHPUnit, it fails to JSON decode and read from `php://input`.

```
    // PHPUnit test
    $request = $this->createJsonRequest('POST', '/hello',
            [
                'foo' => 'bar',
            ]
        )
    $response = $this->app->handle($request);

    ...

protected function createJsonRequest(
    string $method,
    $uri,
    array $data = null
): ServerRequestInterface {
    $request = $this->createRequest($method, $uri);

    if ($data !== null) {
        $request = $request->withParsedBody($data);
    }

    return $request->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

    // controller
    $formData = $this->getFormData();
```

Comment: In this case it makes no sense to read the json from `php://input` because the $request body already contains the json data. Is this slim 4? Which Slim skeleton project are you using?

Comment: I am using Slim 4.5.